# Truffle can not find artifacts

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, truffle-migration

I'm trying to deploy a contract and I don't require *Migrations.sol* in any of my migrations. I don't even have this file in my contracts folder. And I run truffle migrate inside my project folder.
But it says that can't deploy cause can not find artifacts for *Migrations.sol*. And shows me that

> Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
>   Error: Could not find artifacts for ./Migrations.sol from any sources
>       at Resolver.require (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:69108:9)

Please help me understand what's happenning and how do I solve it?

Comment: Can you copy paste the content of your migration file ?

Comment: Yes, it's very simple  >var TeozToken = artifacts.require("./MyToken.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(MyToken);
};  

and

 > var Ownable = artifacts.require("./Ownable.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Ownable);
};

Comment: Can you do a grep on Migrations.sol on your whole project? You will see where you reference this contract

Comment: What do you mean by "grep on"?
I don't reference it in my project  (in the one, I'm trying to deploy)

Comment: i mean the grep command line utility that allow you to search into multiple files.

Comment: @JulienKlepatch
found it in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js

Comment: Sounds like its a required file by truffle itself, which is supposed to be located in truffle dir. Try to reinstall a fresh version of truffle

Comment: Which version of truffle do you use? ££You can find it out with truffle version

Comment: @JulienKlepatch I found "var Migrations = resolver.require("./Migrations.sol" in cli.bundled.js file. I don't understand why it's here, but I just added this file(empty) to my contracts so I could move forward. 
Though, now I have another issue with cli.bundled.js now, I'll ask it as a different question, would appreciate your help.

Comment: @Bumblebee I use Truffle v4.0.1

Comment: Did you try truffle develop

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
var Adoption = artifacts.require("MyToken.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(Adoption);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Running `truffle migrate` requires the `Migrations.sol` that comes with `truffle init` or `truffle unbox`. You won't be able to run migrations without it since that is how the migrate tools track the current state of migrations.